# Duplicate icons in dock, and gear icons in multitasking / window spread views

Tags: applications, plank, icons, multitasking-view

Occasionally, when opening an app, a duplicate (blurrier) icon will appear in the Plank dock, and the app's normal icon already kept in the dock will not display an indicator.

[image: Blurry duplicate of AppCenter icon]

When this happens, said app's window will show a gear icon in multi-tasking view, as shown below, as well as window spread view and the alt-tab switcher as well.

[image: Gear icons over application in Window Spread view]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen exactly the same couple of issues. I can also add that sometimes applications installed from flathub (LibreOffice) can have normal plank icons with no duplicates, but at the same time they have a gear-icon in the multitasking view.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show when you are running the app?

Regardless, normal behavior is to put a dot under the applet for pinned apps and add a gear or icon at the side for unpinned apps.  For some reason some pinned apps will launch the gear or icon anyway.  This is the same as in gnome.  I don't know why but I believe it has something to do with the .desktop file.

If it is annoying you can stop them my CTRL-right click>preferences>behavior and deselect "Show Unpinned".  Of course you will also lose the icons for the apps you don't have pinned as well.